# Scale a range in Dart

Tags: dart, arduino

I'm trying to find a function which does the same thing as the Map() function in Arduino IDE.
I have an int variable that's coming from an ADC. In my arduino code, I use a simple  `int variable = map(variable, 0, 4095 , 0, 100);`
to change the input of that adc to a 0 to 100 but i'd like to do that in Dart.
Is there a simple function for doing this in flutter?

Comment: Do you mean a range of numbers? - from 0 going to 100? Or you want to  just to re-assign the current variable?

Comment: Really just want to change the value or the variable linearly. So 0 would be 0 and 4095 would be 100 and if the variable is anything in between, it works it out. So 2048 would be 50 etc.

Comment: The value of the variable would be unknown and different from user to user. I want to make it so they can essentially “calibrate” these value to a simple 0-100.

Comment: `variable * 100 ~/ 4095`?

Comment: Would that require variable to be a double? Or because it’s an integer, it will ignore the decimals?

Comment: Actually, using that simple math would make it difficult to “calibrate” the value. As the variable could be anything (current testing shows 840) that would need to equate to 0. Same for what the variable would be for 100. 
If it’s not possible, I’ll look into trying to do it on the Arduino end with commands sent from flutter.

Comment: How about `double recalibarate(num value, num fromStart, num fromEnd, num toStart, num toEnd) => (value - fromStart) / (fromEnd-fromStart) * (toEnd - toStart) + toStart;`. You can even have a `int recalibarateInt(int value, int fromStart, int fromEnd, int toStart, int toEnd) => (value - fromStart) * (toEnd - toStart) ~/ (fromEnd-fromStart) + toStart;` which tries to find a matching integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply multiply your new upper range bound by the existing range expressed as a fraction of 1, using the lower range bound as an offset.

```dart
variable = ((upper - lower) * (variable / 4095)) + lower;
```

If you require an integer, you can utilise a rounding or truncation function as well.

Comment: The only problem I still have with that method is the lower range. The original variable value from testing would be 840 (but could be different for another user) that would need to them change to 0. I guess I could use some simple math for that too I suppose but was hoping there would be a simpler function like in Arduino ide (c++?) to reconfigure the variable value.

Comment: There's no inbuilt function to do this in Dart. I will update my answer to work with a lower bound as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself frequently being in need of such a function in my own projects, so I developed the [`num_remap`](https://pub.dev/packages/num_remap) package.

Using that package, you can remap integers like this:

```dart
import 'package:num_remap/num_remap.dart';

...

variable = variable.remapInt(0, 4095, 0, 100);
```